# How to use constant/variable in a SQL Server CE 4 script?

Tags: variables, sql-server-ce, constants

I have this script:

```
DELETE FROM [Tags] WHERE Id = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '7373D1A0-CB6A-4207-87C4-AE2939FD20C0');
GO
INSERT INTO [Tags] VALUES (CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '7373D1A0-CB6A-4207-87C4-AE2939FD20C0'), 'Business');
GO
```

I want to declare a `@businessId` constant to hold the result from my

```
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '7373D1A0-CB6A-4207-87C4-AE2939FD20C0')
```

The end result should look cleaner:

```
DELETE FROM [Tags] WHERE Id = @businessId;
GO
INSERT INTO [Tags] VALUES (@businessId, 'Business');
GO
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server CE 4?
If no, is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL (SQL Server) you would write

```
Declare @businessId UniqueIdentifier;
set @businessId = '7373D1A0-CB6A-4207-87C4-AE2939FD20C0';
```

I would imagine that it is the same in SQL Server CE but I will confirm it;

Comment: I get this error : Declare @businessId UniqueIdentifier
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 14,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = Declare ].
Maybe SQL CE doesn't support the declaration of variables.

Comment: it seems that SQL Server Compact does not allow the declare statement.  you can parameterise a sql command and add the parrameters via the .net SQLCECommand object.  see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056872/29467