# C# Duplicate '\' with SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sha

I have a problem when I run a SQL command and the result is a hashed password **sha 256**

Password in database: `"Z?VU??u2???f?[??\n?Mn??=1???<3?\v?"`

Password returned by c# after the query: `"Z?VU??u2???f?[??\ \n?Mn??=1???<3?\ \v?"`(I put a space because it is deleted by the page)

This is my code:

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPassword.Text);
data = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(data);

String hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

string Command = "Select * From Users where Status=1 and Username='" + txtUser.Text + "'" + " and Password='" + hash + "'";
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, Database.Connection);

da.Fill(dsResult);

if (dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

I saw the error when I try this

```
Select Password 
From Users 
Where Status = 1 
  And Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'"
```

and the result was the password but with duplicate `\`.

In SQL Server Management Studio, this query:

```
Select * 
From Users 
Where Status = 1 
  And Username = 'Rick' 
  And Password = 'Z?VU??u2???f?[??\n?Mn??=1???<3?\v?'
```

works perfectly.

Thank you.

Edit: Injection Changes.

New Code:

```
                SqlDataReader da;
                string Command= @"Select * From Users where Status=1 and Username=@User and Password=@Password";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, Database.Connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Z?VU??u2???f?[??\n?Mn??=1???<3?\v?";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsuario.Text.Replace(" ", "");
                da = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (da.HasRows)
                {
                    da.Read();
                    DoSomething();
                }
```

But the problem persists. When C # executes the query interprets that the password in the database has the double slash then it never matches with the input password

Comment: Did you try setting parameter for command instead of passing direct value?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Duplicating the backslashes is **standard C#** behavior - that's not unusual or cause for concern. The backslash is duplicated to indicate that you really want a backslash - otherwise, it'll be interpreted as an **escape sequence** (together with the next char, e.g. `\t` is `<TAB>`, `\r` is carriage return etc.)

Comment: An effective solution could be hash.Replace("\","\\"); ?

Answer (score 1):

By using [SqlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056872/how-to-pass-variable-into-sqlcommand-statement-and-insert-into-database-table) you can send variable without loosing data and avoid [**SQL Injection**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) like this:

```
string insertString = @"Select * From Users where Status=1 and Username='Rick' and Password=@pass";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(insertString, c);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = "Z?VU??u2???f?[??\n?Mn??=1???<3?\v?";
//And the rest
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the injection. I do some changes but the problem persists. 
When C # executes the query interprets that the password in the database has the double slash then it never matches with the input password